# Directly Plotting ts object with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wonder if there is a function to plot `ts` object directly with ggplot2. In past, I was using the following strategy but now it is throwing an error.

```
set.seed(12345)
dat <- ts(data=runif(n=10, min=50, max=100), frequency = 4, start = c(1959, 2))
df <- data.frame(date=as.Date(time(dat)), Y=as.matrix(dat))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, mapping=aes(x=date, y=Y))+geom_point()
```

**Error**

```
Error in as.Date.default(time(dat)) : 
  do not know how to convert 'time(dat)' to class “Date”
```

How can I directly plot `ts` object with `ggplot2`.

Comment: There is no `as.Date.ts` method. Where is your evidence that this worked in the past?

Comment: @BondedDust: Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25353201/707145) for reference.

Comment: Just use `as.numeric` instead of `as.Date`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

autoplot(as.zoo(dat), geom = "point")
```

or maybe:

```
autoplot(as.zoo(dat), geom = "point") + scale_x_yearqtr()
```

See `?autoplot.zoo` for more info.

**Note:** The code in the question works if you issue the command `library(zoo)` first.

**Updates**  Added second solution, `library(scales)` and switched from `yearmon` to `yearqtr`.

Comment: autoplot(as.zoo(dat), geom = "point") + scale_x_yearmon() does not work for me with the error "Error in as.yearmon(pretty_breaks(n)(x)) : could not find function "pretty_breaks"

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: Would appreciate if you guide me how to get quarters along years in the x-axis. I tried `scale_y_yearqtr(format = "%Y-%q")` but could not get quarters along years. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: My bad. It was typo, I used `scale_x_yearqtr(format = "%Y-%q")`. I want to get something like `1959-Q2`, `1959-Q3`, `1959-Q4` etc in the x-axis.

Comment: Thanks, this shows only the first quarter of the year. How to get all quarters with years? Thanks

Comment: It ultimately uses `scale_x_continuous` so you can use its `breaks` argument: `library(zoo); library(ggplo2); library(scales); z <- as.zoo(dat); breaks <- seq(min(time(z)), max(time(z)), .25);  ... + scale_x_yearqtr(breaks = breaks, format = "%yQ%q")` .

Answer (score 5):

Don't know why it worked before (since it would not seem to be valid under my understanding of Date functins) but you can fix it with the use of zoo::as.yearqtr

```
library(zoo)
?as.yearqtr
set.seed(12345)
dat <- ts(data=runif(n=10, min=50, max=100), frequency = 4, start = c(1959, 2))
df <- data.frame(date=as.Date(as.yearqtr(time(dat))), Y=as.matrix(dat))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, mapping=aes(x=date, y=Y))+geom_point()
# No errors. The plot has YYYY-MM labeling as expected for a ggplot2-Date axis.
```

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me

```
set.seed(12345)
dat <- ts(data=runif(n=10, min=50, max=100), frequency = 4, start = c(1959, 2))
library(ggfortify)
autoplot(dat, geom = "point", ts.colour = ('dodgerblue3')) #Option 1

library(zoo)
autoplot.zoo(as.zoo(dat), geom = "point") #Option 2
```

Comment: Thanks @Rafael for more elegant answer.